# equal width and height flexbox

Tags: html, css

I've two question's about flexboxes but can't find the answer to this.

1. I want to create 4 boxes that have all the same width and the same height without using the viewport. for example: I create one box with a 50% width and the height needs to be equal to the width. All the other boxes get the same properties.
2. If I have those boxes I would like to set div's inside one of those square's, one that takes a height of 20% and the whole width of that box. how can I set the height to 20% and make sure the box doesn't extend?

my code so far:

```css
.flex-container {
  float: none;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;  
   -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-item { 
  width: 50%;
  color: white;
}

.flex1 {
  background-color: green;
   float: left;
}

.flex2 {
  background-color: red;
  float: right;
}

.flex3 {
  background-color: purple;
   float: left;
}

.flex4 {
  background-color: orange;
  float: right;
}

.inlineBox {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item flex1">this boxes that I created here all need to have the same height and width. They need to be responsive and dont use a vieuwport</li>
  <li class="flex-item flex2">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item flex3">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item flex4">4</li>
  
  
</ul>

<br>
<br>
<br>


these yellow box need to take a width of 100% and a height of 20% inside the flex box<br>


<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item flex1">
    <div class="inlineBox"> </div>
    <div class="inlineBox"> </div>
    <div class="inlineBox"> </div>
  
  </li>
  <li class="flex-item flex2">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item flex3">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item flex4">4</li>
  
  
</ul>
```

Comment: can u provide to an snippet?

Comment: thanks for your reaction! what can I do more than provide a code snippet?

Comment: Regarding your 1st question You can play with heights unless and until all the div/li are in one row. In your case you are having two rows of flexbox. Flexbox row row have ability to keep all it;s column height same. But if you are having two rows with there respective columns then the will behaves differently respective to there row height

Comment: is there a way (preferably) in css to get exact the same height? This is displayed on mobile pages as well as large screens so if it is'nt exact the same it looks 
looks awful

Comment: Added answer below, please have look. Hope it will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html code:

```html
<ul class="flex-container">
    <li class="flex-item flex1">
        <span>this boxes that I created here all need to have the same height and width. They need to be responsive and
            dont use a vieuwport</span>
    </li>
    <li class="flex-item flex2"></li>
    <li class="flex-item flex3"></li>
    <li class="flex-item flex4"></li>
</ul>
<br>
<br>
<br>
these yellow box need to take a width of 100% and a height of 20% inside the flex box<br>


<ul class="flex-container">
    <li class="flex-item flex1">
        <div class="item-wrap">
            <div class="inlineBox"> </div>
            <div class="inlineBox"> </div>
            <div class="inlineBox"> </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="flex-item flex2"></li>
    <li class="flex-item flex3"></li>
    <li class="flex-item flex4"></li>
</ul>
```

css code:

```css
.flex-container {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-item {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    padding-top: 50%;
    color: white;
}

.flex-item>span {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.flex1 {
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
}

.flex2 {
    background-color: red;
    float: right;
}

.flex3 {
    background-color: purple;
    float: left;
}

.flex4 {
    background-color: orange;
    float: right;
}

.inlineBox {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 20%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.item-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Explain your code please. How did you resolved the OP's issue, what did you add ?

Comment: padding-top:50% for parent with display: relative and for the child display: absolute width:100% and height: 100%

Comment: I think you should edit your post by first explaining how your result works rather than just givig out code ;-) The goal is to learn more, not just have a fix we don't necesserly understand

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! A question due to the height of the yellow div. You set It to 20% padding-top wich is actualy a really nice solution. One thing I don't get is these padding-top 20% is taking way more than 20% of his parent or am I wrong?

Comment: @sebasT,padding-top is calculated by 20% of the parent width

Answer (score 1):

The answer is NO.
The reason is provided in the flexbox specification:
https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-lines

You can accomplish that now with display: grid:

https://codepen.io/pgurav/pen/eYpeOEp

Although the grid itself is not flexbox, it behaves very similar to a flexbox container, and the items inside the grid can be flex.

The grid layout is also very handy in the case you want responsive grids. That is, if you want the grid to have a different number of columns per row you can then just change grid-template-columns:

```css
grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr); /* 1 column  */
grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); /* 2 columns */
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); /* 3 columns */
```

and so on...

You can mix it with media queries and change according to the size of the page.

Sadly there is still no support for container queries / element queries in the browsers (out of the box) to make it work well with changing the number of columns according to the container size, not to the page size (this would be great to use with reusable webcomponents).

More information about the grid layout:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

Support of the Grid Layout accross browsers:

https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid

Comment: thanks for your answer! It will certainly take some time to work this out because this is completly new to me. One question if I use this method: if I place in one of those grid colum a new div, can I set it to a height of 20% of that particular div?